# Using Cookies in angular Universal (for Angular 6 )

Tags: angular, universal, angular-cookies

I am working on Angular 6 and have installed the Angular universal in it.

I am having issues with package `ngx-cookie-service` as it is not supporting universal ([check this issue for more info](https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service/issues/1)). Kindly help with any other package support or any methods by which I can do rendering using Universal.

Also, for further information I got the following error when tried to access `localhost:8080` after running the command `npm run server`.

```
Listening on: http://localhost:8080
    ERROR Error: NotYetImplemented
        at Document.module.exports.exports.nyi (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:75198:9)

        at CookieService.module.exports.CookieService.check (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:96561:48)

        at CookieService.module.exports.CookieService.get (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:96569:47)

        at new HeaderComponent (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:173317:44)

        at createClass (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:9688:20)
        at createDirectiveInstance (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:9563:20)

        at createViewNodes (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:10783:36)

        at callViewAction (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:11099:13)

        at execComponentViewsAction (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:11018:13)

        at createViewNodes (D:\Alok\angular\mp3online\dist\server.js:10811:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you calling cookie service, you got to do platform check.